Does "array" use smaller font in equation compared with "alignedat" or "aligned" in LaTeX?
Sometimes, it is more convenient to use array to align something in equations in LaTeX. However, the array displays more smaller font compared to the alignedat or aligned.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{alignedat}{10}
            f_\mathrm{1}&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
    \end{alignedat}
    \right\}
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
    \left.
        \begin{aligned}
            f_\mathrm{1}&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
        \end{aligned}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{r@{\:}c@{\:}l}
            f_\mathrm{1}&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


So, how to make the font of array larger?

\displaystyle (in every cell)

@UlrikeFischer This way doesn't work.

array uses \textstyle. Try r @{\:} c @{\:} >{\displaystyle} l to force \displaystyle in the last column (>{...} insert its content before each cell of the column). For your equation, no need to force \displaystyle in the first two columns (\textstyle produces the same output).

@jlab \begin{array}{r @{\:} c @{\:} >{\displaystyle} l} causes an error.

@Y.zeng You need the array package. I had an answer. By the way, your array has 2 columns, not 3.

The array environment uses \textstyle, while equation use \displaystyle. You need to force \displaystyle in every cell.
The columns definition of LaTeX tabular is extended by the array package.  In particular, >{<something>} put <something> before the contents of every cell in the following column.
In your example, you have two columns. \displaystyle is only needed for the second. Use:
\begin{array}{@{} r @{\;} >{\displaystyle} l @{}}

(I corrected the spaces thanks to Mico's comments).
If needed, define a new column type modifier, like
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\displaystyle} #1}

and use @{} r @{\;} D{l} @{} as tabular specification (or define three new colunm types \newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle} c}, \newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle} l}, \newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle} r}).
Full example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\displaystyle} #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{alignedat}{10}
            f_\mathrm{1}&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
    \end{alignedat}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
        \begin{aligned}
            f_\mathrm{1}&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
        \end{aligned}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{@{} D{r} @{\;} D{l} @{}}
            f_\mathrm{1}&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


As alternative you can try the modern package tabularray:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{alignedat}{10}
            f_\mathrm{1}&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
    \end{alignedat}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
        \begin{aligned}
            f_\mathrm{1}&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
        \end{aligned}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \left.
    \begin{tblr}
      {
        colspec = {rl},
        columns = {mode=dmath},
        colsep = 0pt,
      }
      f_\mathrm{1}&{}=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}\\
    \end{tblr}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}



Is there a way to set \displaystyle for array in all places with one command?

Since the alignedat{10}, aligned, and array environments all contain just one row, they by construction can't be performing any meaningful alignment operations. And, to make for a fair comparison of aligned vs array, you should replace \begin{array}{r @{\:} >{\displaystyle} l} with \begin{array}{@{} r @{\;} >{\displaystyle} l @{}}. Yes, that's \;, not \:.

@Mico What is the difference between \; and \: here? Why can't I use @{} instead?

@Y.zeng - The instructions \: and \; insert 4pt and 5pt, resp., of whitespace. Since we're concerned with the spacing around the = symbol (a "relational operator" in TeX jargon), \; is called for. In contrast, \: would be appropriate if we were dealing with the spacing around a "binary operator" symbol such as +, -, and \times.

@Mico Okay. I had no idea there were such detailed default operations before.

@Y.zeng - You also asked, "Why can't I use @{} instead?" I'm afraid I don't understand this question. The suppression of whitespace at the edges of an array environment is an issue that's completely separate from the amount of whitespace that should be inserted around the = symbol in the middle of an array.

@Mico Thank you. I previously thought that the length of these spaces was just a matter of personal preference. I didn't realize there are standardized default parameters.

@Y.zeng You'll find in the edited answer a shorter way to set the tabular specification (through the definition of new column types) and an alternative with tabularray.

I can't see a valid reason for using {alignedat}{10} when there's a single alignment point per row; why not use an {aligned} environment? By the way, neither {alignedat}{10} nor {aligned} are actually doing anything useful in the OP's example, as there's but a single row in each of these environments. Put differently, these environments are not performing anything related to alignment. This problem is actually evident in the OP's screenshot, which shows that the three = symbols are not aligned with each other.
I therefore propose a solution that replaces the three separate equation environments, each containing a one-row {alignedat}{10} environment, with a single align environment. Note that the = symbols are now aligned. Moreover, the contents of an align environment are typeset in display-style math mode by default.
In addition to swiching to a single align environment, I would (a) load the mathtools package, which is a superset of the amsmath package, to (b) define a macro called \norm, and (c) replace all instances of \|\mathrm{AB}\| with \norm{\mathrm{AB}}. Incidentally, there's no point in writing $\mathrm{1}$ instead of just $1$.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f_{1}&=\left.\frac{\norm{\mathrm{AB}}}{\norm{\mathrm{CD}}}\right\}\\
f_{1}&=\left.\frac{\norm{\mathrm{AB}}}{\norm{\mathrm{CD}}}\right\}\\
f_{1}&=\left.\frac{\norm{\mathrm{AB}}}{\norm{\mathrm{CD}}}\right\}
\end{align}
\end{document}


May you tell me what is the meaning of 10 in {alignedat}{10}?

Quoting from the user guide of the amsmath package: "The [alignedat] environment takes one argument, the number of “equation columns” (the number of pairs of right-left aligned columns; the argument is the number of pairs): count the maximum number of &s in any row, add 1 and divide by 2." Since there's a single & symbol, (1+1)/2=1, and hence alignedat{1} would be correct -- which is the same as aligned (without an argument). In no case can 10 be appropriate.

Okay. I know it now. But after having tested it. I found there is no difference between 10 and 1.

@Y.zeng - Luckily for you, LaTeX is set up to "discard" an excess number of columns, in the same way that \begin{tabular}{ c } and \begin{tabular}{ *{100}{c} } may appear to generate the same output if the table contains a single column. Even then, you'll quickly run into cases where there is a difference. Why incur such a risk (and the invariably less-than-fully-helpful error messages)? You're deluding yourself if you think that \begin{alignedat}{10} and \begin{aligned} are equivalent.

Okay. But, count the maximum number of &s in any row, add 1 and divide by 2. Will it be a decimal number, such as 1.5 or 2.5 in other cases?

@Y.zeng - If you're getting a non-integer number, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. Do please take the time to study the relevant section(s) of the user guide of the amsmath package. It'll be time and effort well spent.

For example, there are two & in a row, so (2+1)/2=1.5. Am I wrong?

@Y.zeng - As I already said, if you have an even number of & symbols in an alignedat row, you're' almost certainly doing something wrong. In the example you give, either one of the & symbols is superfluous, or you should actually have 3 & symbols in that row. As I also wrote, do please take the time to study the user guide of the amsmath package. This user guide is exceptionally well written. Are you afraid of reading user guides?

\begin{{alignedat}{2} a&=\frac{t}{g}&=0.5\\ b&=\frac{h}{ff}&=0.33\\ \end{alignedat} This one wouldn't work. But which & should I omit? I will read it now.

@Y.zeng - This is definitely wrong. Unless you're trying to produce something that's utterly unreadable (which I definitely don't recommend...), it should be \begin{alignedat}{2} a&=\frac{t}{g} &&=0.5\\ b&=\frac{h}{ff}&&=0.33 \end{alignedat}. Incidentally, why are you still trying to come up with unusable code that doesn't prove anything instead of studying the user guide of the amsmath package?

I start to read it now as its design is more intricate than I had imagined.

@Y.zeng - Cheer up. You'll find the effort well worth it.

Thanks. I will do my best to understand and remember them.
